# normal distribution with mean and standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution

In an examination the number of marks allotted to each candidate is an integer. If the marks were normally distributed, and the distribution had a mean of 45 and a standard deviation of 12, find the percentage of the candidates who would pass with a pass mark of 40

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $P(X\geq 40)=1-P(X\leq 40)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{40-\mu}{\sigma} \right)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{40-45}{12} \right)$,

where $X \sim \mathcal N(45,12^2)$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. A table for the corresponding probabilities can be found [here](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf).